# Is there a typo in this statement on the uniqueness of maximum likelihood estimators?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

Working through a textbook on maximum likelihood estimation and the following is said:

"the uniqueness of the maximum likelihood estimator is not guaranteed, there may exist at least two parameter values $\hat{\theta}_1\not = \hat{\theta_2}$ with $L(\hat\theta_1)= L(\hat\theta_2)=argmax_{\theta\in{\Theta}}L(\theta)$"

Doesn't "$argmax_{\theta\in{\Theta}}L(\theta)$" represent the value that of $\theta$ that maximises $L(\theta)$, not the maximum value of $L(\theta)$

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Yes. Sloppy notation. Which book?

Comment: Applied Statistical Inference Held and Bové (2014)

Comment: It looks like the authors accidentally wrote "argmax" instead of "max," that's all.